# Magento 2: What is the `component_paths` property in `magento/magento2-base`

Tags: magento2, php, composer, component, paths

In Magento 2, the `magento/magento2-base` package has the following `component_paths` section in its `composer.json` file.

```
"extra": {
    "component_paths": {
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "lib/internal/Credis",
        "components/jquery": [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
        ],
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
        "components/jqueryui": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
    },
```

What is this used for?  It [doesn't appear to be a part of stock composer](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&espv=2&q=site%3Agetcomposer.org+%2B%22component_paths%22&oq=site%3Agetcomposer.org+%2B%22component_paths%22&gs_l=serp.3...8948.11683.0.11972.3.3.0.0.0.0.96.165.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.fNY_dZqzU7U), and a quick text search though Magento's source didn't reveal any obvious uses.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed used as a test that enforces validity of `composer.json` files and any other conventions in Magento components.

You can find the usage of this section in `/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/ComposerTest.php::testComponentPathsInRoot()`. The full method looks like this :

```
public function testComponentPathsInRoot()
{
    if (!isset(self::$rootJson['extra']) || !isset(self::$rootJson['extra']['component_paths'])) {
        $this->markTestSkipped("The root composer.json file doesn't mention any extra component paths information");
    }
    $this->assertArrayHasKey(
        'replace',
        self::$rootJson,
        "If there are any component paths specified, then they must be reflected in 'replace' section"
    );
    $flat = $this->getFlatPathsInfo(self::$rootJson['extra']['component_paths']);
    while (list(, list($component, $path)) = each($flat)) {
        $this->assertFileExists(
            self::$root . '/' . $path,
            "Missing or invalid component path: {$component} -> {$path}"
        );
        $this->assertArrayHasKey(
            $component,
            self::$rootJson['replace'],
            "The {$component} is specified in 'extra->component_paths', but missing in 'replace' section"
        );
    }
    foreach (array_keys(self::$rootJson['replace']) as $replace) {
        if (!MagentoComponent::matchMagentoComponent($replace)) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey(
                $replace,
                self::$rootJson['extra']['component_paths'],
                "The {$replace} is specified in 'replace', but missing in 'extra->component_paths' section"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

So this test case looks like it ensures the all extra components which are using by Magento are configured properly in `composer.json`.

If you find any other usages of this section, please let me know. Thanks for asking this question Alan.

Comment: That test is testing the replace and component_paths matchup, but why is component_paths there in the first place?

Comment: The test ensures that all packages mentioned in "replace" really exist in Magento code, so if a library is removed, its mentioning is removed from `composer.json` as well. As `composer.json` contains information about dependencies, it seems good place for such mapping information as well. It could be in a separate file, but it feels more reliable to keep it in the same place as "replace" list.